# How to get Thread Group number

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to get the Thread Group number of the thread group executing a request so I can correlate it with a property (or maybe a CSV line), but I am having a hard time getting the number alone.

I am able to get the full thread name (including the number) with `thread.getThreadName()`, but I would need to isolate the number from the name and I would like to skip that part if possible.

Methods that I have used:

- `ctx.getThreadGroup().getName()` returns `Thread Group`
- `ctx.getThreadGroup().getThreadName()` returns `null` for some reason
- `ctx.getThreadNum()` returns `0` as it is the first thread to run inside the Thread Group
- `ctx.getThread().getThreadName()` returns `Thread Group 1-1`
- `ctx.getThread().getThreadNum()` returns `0`

I know the number has to be stored somewhere as the log prints this line:

> `2022-07-10 13:31:10,313 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group`

Where can I find this information?

Thank you.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads()` function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/AbstractThreadGroup.html#getNumThreads--)

[image]

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: I actually want to extract the number before the dash which, in your case, would be Thread Group 1-1 through Thread Group 1-5

Comment: In that case you can do something like `def threadGroupName = ctx.getThreadGroup().getName(); def threadName = ctx.getThread().getThreadName(); def threadGroupNumber = (threadName =~ /$threadGroupName\s(\d+)-/)[0][1]; log.info('Thread group number: ' + threadGroupNumber)`. Check out [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.